# Do you have to call setContentView() from onConfigurationChanged()?

Tags: android, screen-rotation

I've set the manifest entry for my Activity so that it handles orientation changes by itself.

In my `onConfigurationChanged()`, I've got this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    findViewById(R.id.header).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    });
}
```

After months of working without problems, I've just had a `NullPointerException` on the `findViewById()` line. My conclusion is that the `View` in question hasn't been created yet, due to the omission of `setContentView()`.

Is `setContentView()` really necessary here? If so, why has it been working all this time without incident?

Comment: No, it's not necessary. Something else in your code is causing the `findVieWById` to return null.

Comment: Felix is probably right. look for where you initialize whatever layout contains R.id.header. it's probably related to that

Comment: @Felix Thanks, you're right, a separate issue was causing that View to be missing. Repost your response as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, calling `setContentView` is not necessary in that situation. Something else in your code is causing the `findVieWById` to return null.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Android Activity Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges):

> If the configuration of the device (as defined by the
>   Resources.Configuration class) changes, then anything displaying a
>   user interface will need to update to match that configuration.
>   Because Activity is the primary mechanism for interacting with the
>   user, it includes special support for handling configuration changes.
>
> Unless you specify otherwise, a configuration change (such as a change
>   in screen orientation, language, input devices, etc) will cause your
>   current activity to be destroyed, going through the normal activity
>   lifecycle process of onPause(), onStop(), and onDestroy() as
>   appropriate. If the activity had been in the foreground or visible to
>   the user, once onDestroy() is called in that instance then a new
>   instance of the activity will be created, with whatever
>   savedInstanceState the previous instance had generated from
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).
>
> This is done because any application resource, including layout files,
>   can change based on any configuration value. Thus the only safe way to
>   handle a configuration change is to re-retrieve all resources,
>   including layouts, drawables, and strings. Because activities must
>   already know how to save their state and re-create themselves from
>   that state, this is a convenient way to have an activity restart
>   itself with a new configuration.
>
> In some special cases, you may want to bypass restarting of your
>   activity based on one or more types of configuration changes. This is
>   done with the android:configChanges attribute in its manifest. For any
>   types of configuration changes you say that you handle there, you will
>   receive a call to your current activity's
>   onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) method instead of being
>   restarted. If a configuration change involves any that you do not
>   handle, however, the activity will still be restarted and
>   onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) will not be called

Basically, you need to ensure that you are saving your instance state, and getting the information back after onConfigurationChanged()

Hope this helps!